# Closed Port on Metaspoilt framework

Tags: ports

I run Kali Linux OS on my PC and I use the Metasploit Framework. But I'm unable to access any ports when I run `sudo netdiscover` it always outputs that all ports are closed, even though Metasploit has a port open.

What do I do?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details. And this is looking like a networking question, not a security question or even about Metasploit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, i'm currently running a beginners course on ethical hacking and i need  to make use of vulnerable machines. apparently i don't have any ports open when i scanned my pc using ```sudo netdiscover``` on my Kali Terminal. this makes it impossible for me to access the built in metaspoilt framework that kali has

Comment: Sure, but can you describe the network between the scanning machine and the target? What you've done is said, "my vehicle won't start" and you haven't said whether you're talking about a car, a bicycle or a container ship. You've described a networking issue. You need to describe the network.

Comment: i don't quite get the question; when i run the mentioned code on my terminal and it starts scanning the available IP's;  the only IP its finds is the one my PC is on, it doesn't find the IP of the metaspoilt framework

Comment: So, you are trying to scan your own machine? And you can't find the *port* that MSF is running on? How do you know what the port is? Have you confirmed using netstat that the port is listening? All this has nothing to do with security and is all basic networking stuff. And you are not providing the details that indicates that you know how networking works. It sounds like you are copying commands and you aren't getting what the tutorial says you should. First learn networking, then learn how to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks, i think this would be of great help to me; but can you kindly recommend any good course you know of that fully covers "Linux" and Information Security also; it seems to be a great tool.